# Error handling in Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

My application runs into errors from time to time and causes the entire thing to crash. I then have to login to the server and restart it each time.

After searching for a while online, I found that `domains` are a great way within Node to deal with error handling. After even further digging, I found that `domains` are now deprecated (no idea why?).

I then found a few answers online that using the following code can be beneficial:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Although, that is simply just for Node, not Express. Therefore, if the code was in the middle of a http request with Express, nothing would be returned to the browser, therefore leaving it in limbo (which can also hog memory on the server).

What is the best way, in NodeJS/ExpressJS, to handle errors while keeping the server running?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a error handler at the end of your `server.js` or its equivalent. 
It can be something like

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (! err) {
        return next();
    }

    res.status(500);

    res.render('path/to/500/page'); // or send out json, what ever you need.
});
```

For catching errors, my preferred way is, `try catch`.

Wrap all your async methods in a promise, or use bluebird to `promisify` it.

In your routes, use `co-express` and `yield` the promises.

**Example**:

```
function mySexyMethod() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        someAsyncMethod(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve(data);
        })
    });
}


/// Express router

const wrap = require('co-express');

router.verb('some-route', wrap(function* (req, res, next) {

    let val;

    try {
        val = yield mySexyMethod();
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e);
    }
});
```

In case there is an error, the error handler, in `server.js`, will be invoked.

As for making sure the node process runs forever on the server, use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Comment: Nice. But implicit exceptions aren’t handled (like trying to access a property that isn’t available on the data object). Like if you were to go `resolve(data123)` instead of `resolve(data)`, Node would just crash instead of sending the error through the middleware error handler.

Comment: @Fizzix -  Yes, that would not be handled by the error handler. In most cases, a linter catches undefined variables but it won't do that for non-existent properties of an object. Let me know if you find a way around this.